# Postfix calculator using Bison

Tags: bison, lex, flex-lexer

Hi I have been trying to create a simple postfix calculator.

Following is the snippet:

```
    %token NUM
    %left '-' '+'
    %left '*' '/'
    %left NEG     /* negation--unary minus */
    %right '^'    /* exponentiation        */

         %% /* Grammar rules and actions follow.  */


    input:
           /* empty */
         | input line
         ;

         line:
           '\n'
         | exp '\n'      { printf ("%.10g\n", $1); }
         ;

         exp:
           NUM           { $$ = $1;           }

         | '-' exp  %prec NEG { $$ = -$2;     }
         | exp exp '+'   { $$ = $1 + $2;      }
         | exp exp '-'   { $$ = $1 - $2;      }
         | exp exp '*'   { $$ = $1 * $2;      }
         | exp exp '/'   { $$ = $1 / $2;      }
         | exp exp '^'   { $$ = pow ($1, $2); }  /* Exponentiation */
         | exp 'n'       { $$ = -$1;          }  /* Unary minus    */
         ;
         %%

   1 2 + 3 -      =>                   0 \n
        1 -2 -      =>                 3 \n
        2 3e+2 + 3 -      =>          299 \n
        1 2 3 + -           =>         -4 \n
```

ONLY, 1 +2 -   =>     :SYNTAX ERROR!!  why is this is the case? what should i do ? I even tried creating a unary + operator but it doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade your lexical analyzer to recognize signed numbers directly as numbers.  Then you don't need the special rule for `'-' exp`, or the `%left NEG` precedence line.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Jonathan.. but how can I make my lexical analyzer to recognize signed numbers directly as numbers? do you have a code snippet or can you give me a headstart pls.

Comment: Should i generate a lexical analyzer first and provide pattern matching in that ? and then add the above code to bison.

Comment: `[-+]?[0-9]+(\.([0-9]+))([eE][-+][0-9]{1,3})?` is a reasonable start to recognizing signed floating point decimal numbers (but I've not validated it; I typed it on the fly).  `[-+]?[0-9]+` looks plausible for decimal integers.  There's an argument for saying that octal and hexadecimal numbers are always unsigned.